# Chrome cannot set the cookie path to "path=/example"

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cookies, path, setcookie

I'm facing an issue with chrome while I'm trying to set a cookie, a read a lot and i still don't understand what is the problem.

the chrome doe's not set the cookie if the path value is not "/".

cookie (works fine):

```
    var dateExpires= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 365 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    var cookieString= encodeURIComponent('cookie-name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent('cookie-value') + ';'
    cookieString += 'sameSite=Lax;'
    cookieString += 'expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + ';'
    cookieString += 'domain=domain.com;'
    cookieString += 'path=/'
    document.cookie = cookieString
```

but if i set the path value to " /examplePath" it doesn't works.

cookie (doesn't works):

```
var dateExpires= new Date(new Date().getTime() + 365 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
var cookieString= encodeURIComponent('cookie-name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent('cookie-value') + ';'
cookieString += 'sameSite=Lax;'
cookieString += 'expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + ';'
cookieString += 'domain=domain.com;'
cookieString += 'path=/examplePath'
document.cookie = cookieString
```

can someone help me to understand what is the issue ?
what am i missing here ?

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

just as a suggestion, try appending a '/' to the end of your path, so:

```
cookieString += 'path=/examplePath/'
```

Comment: does /examplePath already exist?  If not, cookies can't be created.

Comment: /examplePath does not exist, but it's working on Firefox